# Tensor slicing looses the shape information in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to dynamically slice a tensor to automatically adjust its shape for the next iteration. However, I realized that when sliced in Graph mode the shape information of the tensor is lost hence I can not further apply certain operations on it which requires knowing the shape of a given tensor. Below I attached an example code, in my specific example the `opt_with_slicing` function is within a `vectorized_map` which is defined in a larger function that takes care of auto differentiation. Since the original function is too large to include here I simplified it accordingly;

```py
a = tf.constant(np.linspace(0.,10.,11,endpoint=True)[::-1])
b = tf.ones((2,10))

def opt_with_slicing(x, some_cutoff: float):
    a, b = x

    new_size = tf.math.count_nonzero(
        tf.cast(a >= some_cutoff, dtype=tf.int32), dtype=tf.int32
    )
    
    tf.print(f"new size {new_size}, initial size {a.get_shape()}")
    
    test1 = b[:, :new_size]
    test2 = tf.slice(b, [0, 0], [b.get_shape()[0], new_size])
    
    tf.print(f"test1 shape {test1.get_shape()}, test2 shape {test2.get_shape()}")
    return test1, test2

tf.function(opt_with_slicing)([a,b], 5.)  

# Output:
# new size Tensor("count_nonzero/Cast_1:0", shape=(), dtype=int32), initial size (11,)
# test1 shape (2, None), test2 shape (2, None)
# (<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 6), dtype=float32, numpy=
#  array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
#         [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]], dtype=float32)>,
#  <tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 6), dtype=float32, numpy=
#  array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
#         [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]], dtype=float32)>)
```

As you can see from the print out the shape information of `test1` and `test2` is lost and since this is a dynamic operation I have no way to know the `new_size` prior to the execution. Is there a way to reinstate the shape information of the function without breaking the graph mode?

PS: I tried the same with `boolean_mask` as well;

```py
mask = tf.greater_equal(a, some_cutoff)
masked_shape = tf.boolean_mask(a, mask).get_shape()[0]
```

but `masked_shape` turns out to be `None` as well.

System info:

- Tensorflow v2.5.0
- Python v3.8.2

Comment: In graph mode, you should use `tf.shape` rather than the `shape` attribute.

Comment: The reason I'm using `get_shape()` is because functions like SVD are using it (see `tensorflow/python/ops/linalg_grad.py` L823); hence when I use such internal tools, my code crashes since the shape is `None` (see L846 in the same file). Hence I need a way to reinstate the shape of the tensor.